# Jquery is not spotting that a form select has changed

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a db table of all postcodes in the UK and want to create functionality to filter down into local locations to decrease load times of the page. The issue I am having is that I am a bit out of practice with JQuery and there seems to be an issue where selecting the country is not being picked up by the JQuery.

Here is the HTML/PHP for the select:

```
<label for="country_select">
    Select Country
</label>
<select id="country_select" name="country_select" class="form-control search-select">
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
<?PHP
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT(`country`) as countrylist FROM `postcodes`")) {
while($member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $country=$member['countrylist'];
    ?>
    <option value="<?PHP echo $country; ?>"><?PHP echo $country; ?></option>
<?PHP
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

Here is the PHP to check for the post and create a mysql statment to then create another drop down for cities. I am wondering if the issue lies here, i added an echo to see if it appears when the option has been changed, but nothing is appearing.

```
<?PHP
if (isset($_POST['CountryID'])) {
     $country_query = $_POST['CountryID'];
    $statement = " AND `country` = '".$country_query."' ";
    echo $statement;
}
?>
```

And here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#country_select").change(function () {
        var country_name = $("#country_select").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data:  {CountryID: country_name},
            success: function(data){ 
                if(data.success == true){ 
                   alert('success'); 
                }
            }               
        });
    });
});
```

I am unsure where I am going wrong as it has been a while since I have coded. I have looked around at others' issues with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `i added an echo to see if it appears when the option has been changed, but nothing is appearing`... Well you've written `if(data.success == true){ 
                   alert('success'); 
                }` instead of just `alert(data)` in the JS so it's not surprising you don't see anything. What the JS is expecting doesn't match what you're echoing (expecting object vs echoing plain text string). There's probably a console error in the browser I would guess (assuming it's actually executing the Ajax call at all - have you actually debugged any of this properly?)

Comment: How do you know jquery is not triggering the change event? Have you tried putting an alert() / console.log() in onchange function? Is the browser’s network tab showing any ajax request being made?

Comment: *not spotting that the `select` has changed* - but your "check" is inside the ajax callback - which only occurs if it has changed.  Add a `console.log` directly inside the `.change` callback `$("#country_select").change(function() { console.log("change event"); ...` to check if "jquery is spotting that the select has changed" - if that works, then update your question to the **actual problem**.

Comment: *here is PHP for the POST, I'm wondering if the issue is here* - if the issue is whether the select event fires, then *clearly the problem is not in the php that runs when the event fires*.    Please update with the actual issue.

Comment: *unsure of the issue* (paraphrased) - that's ok, we're here to help (honestly).   First step is to find *where* the problem is - and that means just one or two lines of code at a time.  Make sure the event fires (console.log as above).  Make sure the ajax runs (browser network tab).  Make sure your php returns *something* (browser network tab or step-through the php).   Check what it returns in the `success:` directly (`console.log(data)`).   Check if your condition exists `console.log(data.success)`.  At all steps keep the browser console (F12) open and look for errors.

Comment: Then, you'll probably have your own answer.

Comment: The `data` in `success: function(data)` is what is returned by you from your php code.  If you didn't add a `success` property, then there won't be one in jquery's `data`

Comment: I have tried firebug in firefox and chrome developer tools but am not seeing anything being fired when I change the select. Also change the alert to alert(data); but no joy. Could something be interfeering with it?

Comment: Hard to know...in this demo using some dummy option data: https://jsfiddle.net/hdeq74p6/2/ you can see by watching the console that it detects the selection correctly, and then tries to fire the post (which obviously fails since it can't see your server, but that's not the point of the demo). So if you reckon it's not working your page then yes something odd is happening. Potentially the Javascript is not loaded into the same page as the select properly, or there's a script error elsewhere which is causing no Javascript to run - are there any other console errors present?

Comment: No other console errors present. I get nothing in console when i change the select but do when i use your example. POST https://fiddle.jshell.net/hdeq74p6/2/show/?editor_console= 404

Comment: (P.S. If your Javascript/jquery code is in a separate .js file, you can check whether it gets loaded properly into your page by opening your browser's developer tools, going to the Network tool and then loading/refreshing your page. If you see the .js file loaded with a 200 (OK) response then it should be included correctly in the page. Any other response (or the absence of an entry for that file) indicates a possible problem.)

Comment: Og god! somethings made it suddenly work! I see England when I change the select all of a sudden. All i did was copy your jquery from the example. I must have had an error in there somewhere.... Let me update the post. Thanks ADyson :)

Comment: That's great. Post it below as an answer, if you got a working solution. Don't update your _question_ with the _answer_ :-) (see https://stackoverflow.com/tour for more about how things work round here...)

Comment: One last question mate. When I do: 

            success: function(data){ 
    alert(data); 
    console.log(data);
I get the whole html to appear inside of console (although it is showing the select change inside of this html with the echo), is this normal? I would have thought it should only be: {CountryID: country_name}?

I am showing my lack of knowledge of dev :)

Comment: It shows whatever the PHP echoes (and whatever the script contains as non-PHP static text). If you let it output all that, then yes it would show that. If you don't want it to output all that then I suggest either a) make it `exit();` the PHP script at the end (inside) of the `if (isset($_POST['CountryID'])) {` block so no more output can happen, or b) move that functionality to a separate script which the AJAX calls, so it only deals with that one task, instead of jumbling it together with the code which produces the main page.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. thanks.

Comment: `I would have thought it should only be: {CountryID: country_name}`...it would never echo that, that isn't what PHP is outputting. Don't mix up `data:` the $.ajax option with `data` the response variable from the "success" callback. If it helps, you can write `success: function(response){  alert(response);` instead so you don't get confused. You can call the variable whatever you like in fact - `success: function(swkjhgkjhfjgeg){ alert(swkjhgkjhfjgeg)` will work just as well (although possibly be less readable for debugging!)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the jquery. The code should be the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#country_select").change(function () {
    var country_name = $("#country_select").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:  {CountryID: country_name},
        success: function(data){ 
            alert(data); 
        }
    });
});
});`
```